# Sharing data between 2 scripts using 2 text files.(Python)

Tags: python, multithreading, file, text, sharing

I'm trying to share Data between 2 python scripts that are running at the exact same time.

Here is an image to explain how im doing this.
http://i859.photobucket.com/albums/ab153/coreystj/Problem_zps9acdd726.png

This is all done in python. The problem im having is that whenever i Have new information to append to `ClientSend.txt` file(from script 2) it sometimes doesnt register for script 1 to send it to the server. I was thinking maybe its because when i append and write the same file at the exact same time, i end up by accidentally deleting the information before sending it to the server!

How Can i avoid accidentally deleting the contents before sending it. If there is no solution, how else can i share information between two scripts without using socket or any sort of tcp connection.

Script 2 is actually Blender FYI. So multiprocessing, and threading is NOT an option for script two. It simply doesn't support those modules.

Comment: Almost sounds like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for your text method. -- Are you saying when you read/write to the same file, sometimes reading will overwrite it because it's not locking the file during the writes?

Comment: That's right. Because I want this method to be flawless, when i write and append to the file at the exact same time, the file deletes the appended information before sending it tot he server. Its all happening at the exact same frame which is unreliable.

Comment: I cannot se that image, site asks to log in.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the actor model described at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model

Comment: Actors Use Threads, Threading doesnt work with Blender. I tried it, i thought it was gonna work, but it froze my game.